# LINQ To Entities and how to make this simple query work

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
    private void InsertLinks(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        EntityDataModelContext context = DataContext.GetDataContext();
        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            string url1 = url;
            if (context.Links.Any(l => MatchUrlHash(l.UrlHash, url1)))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Link link = new Link
            {
                Url = url,
            };
            context.Links.AddObject(link);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool MatchUrlHash(long urlHash, string url)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(encoded);
        long hash = BitConverter.ToInt64(checksum, 0);
        return urlHash == hash;
    }
```

How can I convert this query to something that still performs decently and doesn't throw any `NotSupportedException`s?

Comment: By the way, call dispose or better use `using` statement for your Context instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF doesn't know how to build SQL query with `MatchUrlHash`. You can simply prepare url hash beforehand and use regular style comparison, `==`.

```
private long CreateUrlHash(string url)
{
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
    byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(encoded);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(checksum, 0);
}

// ...
long urlHash = CreateUrlHash(url);
if (context.Links.Any(l => l.UrlHash == urlHash))
{
   continue;
}
```

Comment: which incidentally is also much more efficient

Comment: Why can't `EF` handle queries like this? As far as I remember `L2SQL` could.

Comment: @Nico - What would the SQL query look like that includes your MatchUrlHash method?  How would L2S or EF know how to translate that method to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass your MatchUrlHash to a sql entity provider. So either pull all records and then run custom logic `context.Links.ToList().Any(l=>MatchUrlHash(l.UrlHash, url1))`

nah.. just rewrite the whole thing

```
private void InsertLinks(IEnumerable<string> urls)
   {
       EntityDataModelContext context = DataContext.GetDataContext();

       var withhashes=urls.Select(u=>new {Url=u,Hash= Hash(u)});
       withhashes.Where(h=>!context.Links.Any(l=>l.UrlHash==h.Hash))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(h=> {
            context.Links.Add(new Link(){
                   Url = h.Url
                   });
               });

          context.SaveChanges();



   }

   private bool Hash( string url)
   {
       SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
       byte[] encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
       byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(encoded);
       long hash = BitConverter.ToInt64(checksum, 0);
       return  hash;
   }
```